# Wpf Fluent Ribbon Menu Keytips hiding when expanding

Tags: wpf, ribbon, fluent, fluent-ribbon

I have Fluent Ribbon control. The Ribbon menu item Keytips are showing incorrectly,

before, 
[image]

after,
[image]

I have fixed row height for ribbon menu.. how to solve the prob, thanks

Here is my code:

```
<Fluent:Ribbon AutomaticStateManagement="True" x:Name="ribbon" IsAutomaticCollapseEnabled="False" IsMinimized="True">
  <Fluent:Ribbon.ContextualGroups>
      <Fluent:RibbonContextualTabGroup x:Name="tabGroup1"  
           BorderBrush="#FF9D00" Background="#FF9D00" Foreground="#C45300"
           Header="FIRST" Visibility="Visible" />
  </Fluent:Ribbon.ContextualGroups>

  <Fluent:Ribbon.Menu>
     <Grid>
       <Fluent:ApplicationMenu Header="File" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=UseApplicationMenu, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">
           <Fluent:ApplicationMenu.RightPaneContent>
              <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical" Width="1000">
                   <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                                            BorderBrush="#64647F" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0">    
                       <TextBlock Text="Recent files" Background="#F6F7F8" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="12,4,4,4" Foreground="#64647F" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="12" />
                   </Border>
             <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="2">
                 <Border Height="1" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="#DCDDDE" />
                 <Border Height="1" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="#FEFEFF" />
               </StackPanel>
             </StackPanel>
          </Fluent:ApplicationMenu.RightPaneContent>

         <Fluent:MenuItem Header="New" Icon="pack://application:,,,/WpfSwastik;component/Images/GreenLarge.png">
         <Fluent:MenuItem Header="Text document" Icon="pack://application:,,,/WpfSwastik;component/Images/GreenLarge.png" />
         <Fluent:MenuItem Header="Spreadsheet" Icon="pack://application:,,,/WpfSwastik;component/Images/GreenLarge.png" />
         </Fluent:MenuItem>
         <Fluent:MenuItem Header="Save As" IsSplited="True" Icon="pack://application:,,,/WpfSwastik;component/Images/BlueLarge.png">
         <Fluent:MenuItem Header="Standard format" Description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna." ToolTip="Save something in standard format"                                                 Icon="pack://application:,,,/WpfSwastik;component/Images/BlueLarge.png" />
       <Fluent:MenuItem Header="Export" ToolTip="Export something" Icon="pack://application:,,,/WpfSwastik;component/Images/BlueLarge.png" />
       /Fluent:MenuItem>
       <Fluent:MenuItem Header="Open" Description="CTRL + O"                                            ToolTip="Open object" Icon="pack://application:,,,/WpfSwastik;component/Images/YellowLarge.png" />

       <Separator />
         <Fluent:MenuItem Header="Exit" Icon="pack://application:,,,/WpfSwastik;component/Images/RedLarge.png"                                              KeyTip="X" Command="{Binding ExitCommand}" />
         </Fluent:ApplicationMenu>
       </Grid>
    </Fluent:Ribbon.Menu>

    <Fluent:RibbonTabItem x:Name="masterTabItem"                                      Header="Master" KeyTip="M" Group="{Binding ElementName=tabGroup1, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Fluent:RibbonGroupBox Icon="pack://application:,,,/WpfSwastik;component/Images/Default.png" x:Name="accountInfo" Header="Acount Info" CanAddToQuickAccessToolBar="False" IsLauncherVisible="False" Padding="25,25,25,24">
        <Fluent:Button Header="Bank" Click="BankMaster" Icon="Images\Green.png" LargeIcon="Images\GreenLarge.png" />
        <Fluent:Button Header="Cash" Click="CashAccount" Icon="Images\Green.png" LargeIcon="Images\GreenLarge.png" />
        <Fluent:Button Header="Customer" Click="CustomersMaster"                                       Icon="Images\Green.png" LargeIcon="Images\GreenLarge.png" />
        <Fluent:Button Header="Supplier" Click="SupplierMaster"                                       Icon="Images\Green.png" LargeIcon="Images\GreenLarge.png" />
        <Fluent:Button Header="Ledger" Click="LedgerMaster"                                          
         Icon="Images\Green.png" LargeIcon="Images\GreenLarge.png" />
        <Fluent:Button Header="Other Charges" Click="OtherExpanses" Icon="Images\Green.png" LargeIcon="Images\GreenLarge.png" />
       <Fluent:Button Header="Annoncements"                                      Icon="Images\Green.png" LargeIcon="Images\GreenLarge.png" />
        <Fluent:Button Header="Alerts" Icon="Images\Green.png" LargeIcon="Images\GreenLarge.png" />
      </Fluent:RibbonGroupBox>
   </Fluent:RibbonTabItem>
</Fluent:Ribbon>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see an example of `KeyTip` in `FluentRibbon`:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Fluent:Ribbon>
        <!--Backstage-->
        <Fluent:Ribbon.Menu>
            <Fluent:Backstage>
            </Fluent:Backstage>
        </Fluent:Ribbon.Menu>
        <!--Tabs-->
        <Fluent:RibbonTabItem Header="Tab">
            <Fluent:RibbonGroupBox Header="Group">
                <Fluent:Button Name="buttonGreen" Header="Green"  Icon="Images\cut.jpg" LargeIcon="Images\cut.jpg"
                           Fluent:KeyTip.AutoPlacement="False" Fluent:KeyTip.HorizontalAlignment="Center" Fluent:KeyTip.VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Fluent:KeyTip.Keys="C" />
                <Fluent:Button Name="buttonGray" Header="Grey" Icon="Images\cut.jpg" LargeIcon="Images\cut.jpg" Fluent:KeyTip.AutoPlacement="False"
    Fluent:KeyTip.HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fluent:KeyTip.VerticalAlignment="Center"  Fluent:KeyTip.Keys="L" />
            </Fluent:RibbonGroupBox>
        </Fluent:RibbonTabItem>
    </Fluent:Ribbon>

    <Button Content="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

**Update:**

I've just set `Height=Auto` and it works okay:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">
   <Border Height="Auto" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="#DCDDDE" />
   <Border Height="Auto" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="#FEFEFF" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I am added keytip for Robbon tab item. I am pressing Alt key it shows correctly. But again I am pressing Alt key when expanding ribbon menu shows 2nd picture(above). I want second time I am pressing Alt key the menu should collapsed.

Comment: @KirubaBlaze please post your the whole XAML. It is hard to say withou code. I cannot reproduce your behavior.